# JAVA - Finding the average value of a double type Array - my code doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, average, operation

My code supposed to do following:

1. Add up all the double values from this particular array:  double `nums[] = {10.5, 11.50,12.50,13.50,14.50}`
2. After that it should be divided by 5 or nums.length

All in all I should get 1 result, but my code is showing me nums[i]/5 for each element individually.

Please check my code and tell me, what I did wrong.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        double [] nums = {10.5, 11.50,12.50,13.50,14.50};  
        double result = 0;
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<nums.length;i++){
            result = result+nums[i];
            System.out.println("Average is "+ result/5);
        }
  
     }

}
```

My current code is displaying following:

```
Average is 2.1
Average is 4.4
Average is 6.9
Average is 9.6
Average is 12.5
```

Comment: You've put the print-statement within the loop. Why do you expect it to print only once?

Comment: Because I copied this exactly the same as in this bloody book and I expect it to work, apparently the book is BS. And I paid over 40 pounds for the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the printing line out of the loop so that the average is printed only once.

```
for(i=0; i<nums.length;i++){
    result = result+nums[i];        
}

System.out.println("Average is "+ result/5); // Moved out from the loop body
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the average also inside the loop. What you would wanna do is something like this :

```
for(i=0; i<nums.length;i++)
    result = result+nums[i];
System.out.println("Average is "+ result/5);
```